# Reason employers re-post a job while they are still interviewing candidates?

Tags: interviewing, job-description, employer

Why would employers re-post a job even though they are already interviewing candidates? Is this usually a sign of a "fake" job posting?

Comment: If they post the job and are interviewing, why do you think it is "fake"?

Comment: Huh? Why would employers stop searching for new candidates if they haven't found the right one yet?

Comment: how big is the company?

Comment: Let's go over the basics once again. When a company has a positions to fill, they post job ads hoping that this would lead to applications from candidates looking for a job. Then they go through the hiring process and would hopefully choose one or more qualified candidates to fill the positions. If they take down the job ads, nobody outside has any way to know that these open positions exist, and consequently candidates have no reason to apply, making it impossible to fill the positions. Hence, it makes sense for companies to keep the job ads till the positions get filled.

Comment: I guess I should've been more specific: The company had this position for 4+ months (renewing it every couple of weeks) I've interviewed with this company and was told there was only one opening. That's why I asked the question as to why companies would post jobs they know they don't plan to hire for

Comment: `why companies would post jobs they know they don't plan to hire for` 

I *do not* think that the interviewing process lasting >= 4 months implies that the company has no intention of hiring someone to fill that position...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why would employers re-post a job even though they are already
>   interviewing candidates?

Because they haven't yet hired someone for the job. It only makes sense to keep looking for the best candidate until you hire one.

It's the same reason you should keep interviewing with several potential employers until you are actually offered and accept a job.

Answer (score -1):

How a company advertises depends on the size of the company and the type of job being advertised.

In large companies with thousands of employees many job posting look identical. They a looking for somebody to serve as X with 1-Y years of experience and a bachelors degree. Many divisions, branches, programs, projects, and teams can use people with those basic skills.

Some companies will constantly advertise some of their basic positions all the time and then grab a bunch of recent resumes when ever they need to hire. They may have enough jobs in a large city to not need to get specific about the location.

In other cases they will advertise for a position, set a closing date in a week or two, and then start the interview process right after the deadline. Then immediately run an almost identical advertisement with just a different position number.

Sometimes positions are always open because they are having trouble finding person who can fill the position. It can be for many reasons. They are having trouble getting candidates, the skill set is rare, the person making the hiring decision is unable to make a decision, or they have multiple openings.

Knowing how they advertise positions can help when applying. In the case with specific closing periods it is fine to apply to the next job opening because they are being filtered and interviewed by a different team who is looking to fill their opening. In the case where they are constantly open you might want to apply every  few months to make sure you still have a fresh application in the system.